# I have an edge that does not bevel as expected, what might be wrong?

Tags: modeling

Here is video of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rAeFdRckN0

What might be wrong with those edge to bevel in such way?

Edit1 : Here is dropbox link to file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7lc0zirimptwcm/wheel.blend?dl=0

Comment: Can you upload the file?

Comment: @OmarAhmad When suggesting that someone should upload a file it is better to suggest *where* they should upload it. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ is the preferred location.

Comment: I've just gotta say, we've been getting a lot of low-quality questions from new users lately... but this one is really good. It's a generic question, simply and clearly asked, with sufficient supporting information, and without editorializing. Good job, @EvgeniPetrov

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beveling ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices) is not a good idea : results are not really predictable.

Here is a view of the inner geometry with triangles (on the right) :

[image]

The upper part of your mesh is good, but the ngon part does not allow to manipulate it well (for beveling, for instance).

So for a good bevel, you should redo this part with quads only (faces composed of 4 vertices), the same way you modeled the upper part.

Also take care of the bottom part (on the left) which is composed of 5 vertices.

**To 'repair' the mesh**

- Go to edit mode
- First of all, select all and remove double vertices (some are doubled)
- Set *face selection mode* by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> then *face*
- Select the two faces which are ngons then delete this faces (<kbd>X</kbd> then *'only faces'*)

[image]

- Set *vertices selection mode* by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> then *'vertex'*
- Select the vertices like below in order to count them (here 18)

[image]

- Give 18 cut on the bottom part (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>Page Up</kbd> 17 times)

[image]

- Select the top and bottom vertices on one side (without the extremities)
- Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and *'bridge edge loops'*

[image]

- Do the same for the other side

Now we have this below, so simply complete the faces for the extremities.

[image]

- Beveling :

[image]

Comment: ....and this is a good, clear, simple answer, too. Good job.

Comment: Is there easy way to seperate face to more faces?

Comment: @EvgeniPetrov, edited

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the great answer! "Bridge Edge Loops" is what I really was looking forward, did it manually :/

Comment: @EvgeniPetrov, doing it manually can be fast too if you use the 'F2' addon (mesh_f2.py)